# Regarding ufw firewall

Tags: 12.10, ufw

I am using Gproxy software in my computer(Ubuntu 12.10). I  want to allow incoming connection from only one IP adress,so that he can use internet. what settings should I configure in ufw firewall.

Comment: IS the connection a local (192.168.*, 10.0.*) or a public IP?  What port is Gproxy listening on?

Comment: Yes,local connection. Port : 5123

Comment: I provided an answer below that should work for the UFW rules.  I also provided the `iptables` equivalent for more technical people, feel free to ignore everything below the horizontal line in my answer.  (If you had said a public IP, i'd be asking you quite a few more questions before giving an answer :P)

Answer (score 1):

For UFW, you should make an Inbound rule which will allow you to accept connections via port 5123 (probably TCP and UDP).

`sudo ufw allow proto tcp from [SourceIP] port 5123` should be sufficient for what you need, it'll open port 5123.

---

For the record, and for those who use `iptables` directly in case you are curious, the same functionality can be obtained with this:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s [SourceIP] --dport 5123 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: to restrict access to a single ip add ` from <IP>` to the ufw command; a more complete example: `sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.42.84 port 5123`

Comment: Thanks, updated accordingly.  Although if it needs UDP, they'll need to add a rule to allow for UDP too.  (I use `iptables`, hence the `iptables` equivalent rules being included)

Comment: @MadhuPrudhviRaj don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped.